# objectivec - nsrange calculation is strange

Tags: objective-c, nsrange

It is strange. I expected that the last NSLog print 3 but it wasn't

```
NSString *value = @"0(234)6";

NSRange beginParenthesis = [value rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange endParenthesis = [value rangeOfString:@")"];

if (beginParenthesis.location != NSNotFound && endParenthesis.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"%ld", endParenthesis.location); // 5
    NSLog(@"%ld", beginParenthesis.location + 1); // 2
    NSLog(@"%ld", endParenthesis.location - beginParenthesis.location + 1); // 5?
}
```

And I saved beginParenthesis.location + 1 to variable...it worked well I expected...why?

```
NSRange beginParenthesis = [value rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange endParenthesis = [value rangeOfString:@")"];

if (beginParenthesis.location != NSNotFound && endParenthesis.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSInteger start = beginParenthesis.location + 1;
    NSLog(@"%ld", endParenthesis.location); //5
    NSLog(@"%ld", start); // 2
    NSLog(@"%ld", endParenthesis.location - start); // 3
}
```

What differece between theses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maths Problem:

endParenthesis.location - beginParenthesis.location + 1  gives u ( 5 - 1 + 1) i.e equal to5 .
But endParenthesis.location - start   gives u 5 - 2 i.e 3.

So  you put the parenthesis like this:

```
 NSLog(@"%ld", endParenthesis.location - (beginParenthesis.location + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its called Operator precedence. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).